# Combining inner json array with space and outer with newline

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script

I have an array defined as,

```
var array = [[
    ["a"],
    ["t"]
], [
    ["b"],
    ["t"]
], [
    ["c"],
    ["t"]
]]
```

The desired output is :

```
a t
b t
c t
```

I have tried with

```
rows.join("\n")
```

which give

```
a,t
b,t
c,t
```

I have a huge list, which needs the highly efficient code that maps each of the inner arrays instead traditional for, while loops

Comment: can't map an array without using loops. Even `Array.prototype` methods use loops internally. Where is this output supposed to be used?

Comment: Your array seems invalid, double check what you have provided.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for the outer array with the line feed and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with `' '` for inner and with `'\n'` for outer arrays.

```js
var array = [
        [["a"], ["t"]],
        [["b"], ["t"]],
        [["c"], ["t"]]
    ],
    result = array.map(function (a) { 
        return a.join(' ');
    }).join('\n');

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var array = [
        [["a"], ["t"]],
        [["b"], ["t"]],
        [["c"], ["t"]]
    ],
    result = array.map(a => a.join(' ')).join('\n');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Join function does not work for nested array. You can use following way to handle such situation.

```
var array = [
    [    ["a"],    ["t"]    ], 
    [    ["b"],    ["t"]    ],
    [    ["c"],    ["t"]    ]
    ];

    for (var i=0, l=array.length; i<l; i++){
        if (array[i] instanceof Array){
            array[i] = array[i].join(" ");
        }
    }
    var energy = array.join('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

All array methods are fancy but may be you can still simply do like

```js
var arr = [[["a"],["t"]],
           [["b"],["t"]],
           [["c"],["t"]]
          ],
 result = arr.join("\n").replace(/,/g," ");
console.log(result);
```